# How to write jasmine unit test case for chrome.identity.getAuthToken()?

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome-app, jasmine2.0

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function (token :any) {

var url = 'http://"
   //the code goes here

});
```

I am not able to cover the code inside the getAuthToken function. I have mocked getAuthToken in following way in my spec.

```
chrome = {
      notifications: {
        clear: function(){}
      },
      identity: {
          getAuthToken: function() {
          }
        },
      storage: {
        local: {
          remove: function() {
          },
          get: function() {
          },
          clear: function() {
          }
        }
      }
```

can anyone please help me or suggest how to cover getAuthToken function.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error you get right now? Or is your locked function simply not called?

Comment: the function is not getting called I am not getting any error

Comment: Did you override `chrome` before their code was even imported? If not, try changing properties on the existing chrome object, rather than replacing it altogether.